# Arguments passed to Action failing using ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i posted code following. no value of arguments founded at controller side.
null value appear at `DeleteCategory(Guid id)`.

my model code is it normal, no error in model.

```
        public Guid CID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters    long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Category Name" )]
        public string Category { get; set; }



        public List<CategoryViewModel> cat;

        public CategoryViewModel() {

            cat = new List<CategoryViewModel>();

        }
```

my veiw code is here i pass arguments in actionlink to controller. it call controller   correctly but argument value of controller always remain null.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in r) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |

              @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCategory", "Admin", new { id = item.CID })

        </td>
    </tr>
```

my routeconfig.cs is as following. i didnot edit it.

```
         public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
         {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}

            );
```

my controller code is: here is a controller in which i m passing argument. but value of id always remain same.

```
        public PartialViewResult DeleteCategory(Guid? id)
        {
            CategoryViewModel cc = new CategoryViewModel();
            ssp_category_ID_Result cs;
            try
            {
                cs = new      GenericList<ssp_category_ID_Result(sce.ssp_category_ID(id).GetEnumerator()).Single();
                cc.Category = cs.CategoryName;
                cc.CID = cs.CID;
                return PartialView("_DeleteCategoryPartial", cs);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ModelState.AddModelError("",ex.Message);
            }
            return PartialView("_DeleteCategoryPartial"); 


        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteCategory(CategoryViewModel cs)
        {
            try
            {
                sce.dsp_category(cs.CID);
                ModelState.AddModelError("","Deleted");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("",ex.Message);
            }

            return View("Category");

        }
```

please anyone guide me why i could find any value of argument at controller agrument

Comment: What URL is generated for the action?

Comment: Indeed, what does the raw HTML look like? What's the value of `item.CID`?

Comment: item.CID is GUID value of specific category.

Comment: http://localhost:5841/Admin/DeleteCategory?Length=5

Comment: Use `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCategory", "Admin", new { id = item.CID }, null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your using the wrong overload, you're trying to use:

```
ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, Object)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx

when you should be using:

```
ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx

so change your code to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCategory", "Admin", new { id = item.CID }, new{})
```